# Javascript to change entire div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

i have a website in which products are listed.There are around 30 products.Now there are links to go to details of each product.I want to put them all on one page and through javascript,change the content of a particular div on click.
What i know is that i can create 30 functions to change the display of 1 div to none..and displaying the other one....
how to achieve this..I am doing something like this

```
function changeImg2() 
{
 $('#change_content').stop(true, true).fadeOut({ duration: slideDuration, queue: false }).css('display', 'none');
 $('#change_content2').stop(true, true).fadeIn({ duration: slideDuration, queue: false });     
}
```

here is the type of div's that i have

```
<div id="change_content1">
                              <div class="viewport">
        <a id="btn" href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/matt_bango/3479048548/">
            <span class="dark-background">Northern Saw-whet Owl <em>Photo by Matt Bango</em></span>
            <img src="images/HAND HELD POWER CUTTERS.jpg" alt="Northern Saw-Whet Owl" />
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="viewport no-margin">
        <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/matt_bango/3478879694/">
            <span class="dark-background">Red-shouldered Hawk <em>Photo by Matt Bango</em></span>
            <img src="images/LIGHTING TOWERS.jpg" alt="Red-shouldered Hawk" />
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="viewport">
        <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/matt_bango/3478189088/">
            <span class="light-background">Blue-headed Vireo <em>Photo by Matt Bango</em></span>
            <img src="images/MAGNETIC STAND DRILLS.jpg" alt="Blue-headed Vireo" />
        </a>
    </div>

   <div><input name="back" value="back" id="back_btn1" type="button"></div>
</div>
```

But this code is not ok...because i'll have to repeat it for 30 div's.Is there a cleaner way to achieve this.

Comment: show your sample html content, **and remember:** you never really need to make the same   function more than 1 times.

Comment: i just added the type of div i want to replace...The problem is how to refer to the div that is on display currently and hide it...and then display the other div through the button...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
$('.myDiv').click(function() {
    $('.myDiv').hide(); //Or whatever function you like
    $(this).show(); //or whatever function you like
});
```

The idea is it hides all divs with the same class and then `$(this)` is used to manipulate the individual div that was clicked on.

You can either target all the divs by giving them a similar class, or if they are all within a parent wrapper use something like `$('.parent-wrapper > div')`

ANSWER to Comment:

`$(this)` when used within an event such as a click function relates to the element which the event was triggered on. In this instance it would be a click event on a single div, which means you can use it to manipulate that div without targeting the others.

As mentioned above using a similar class or selector will allow you to target all divs so you can manipulate them as a group. Note that the target div will likely be included, so manipulate the group BEFORE the target div.

Alternatively you can use `$(this).siblings()` to manipulate all the other divs, if they are on the same level as the div that was clicked, i.e. they are siblings.

Comment: i want to access the div that is currently on display...and the one who's link i clicked..and then hide the div that is on display...can you please elaborate...i dnt know much javascript
how will $(this) refer to the div on display...?

Comment: how will this refer to the div on the display..can you please explain..sorry its a bit hard to understand...
I understood the rest about using the class..

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about what it is you are trying to achieve, although if you need to keep track of divs on display which aren't the one that is clicked, try using addClass() / removeClass() to keep track of divs. Try explain it to me in more detail, and i'll try help. I've +1ed you so you got enough rep to +1 back now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need on() function.
This may be implemented like:

```
jQuery.yourCallback = function () {
  //this here is object, on which triggered event
  //your code may be below
  jQuery(".currentactivediv").removeClass(".currentdiv").hide();
  jQuery(this).addClass(".currentdiv").show();
}
jQuery(".yourdivs").on("click",jQuery.yourCallback);
```

If you want it work with links, you need to locate needed div at DOM where you use jQuery(this).

How it works: when div is showing - script assigns calss .currentactivediv to this div.
When other div is showing - script closes current div, removes .currentactivediv class from it and assigns this class to new div, what is showing.

Comment: i want to access the div that is currently on display...and the one who's link i clicked..and then hide the div that is on display...can you please elaborate...i dnt know much javascript

Comment: Try adding a class to current div when you handle click event from link. Code will be like: jQuery(".currentactivediv").removeClass(".currentdiv").hide(); jQuery(".newdiv").addClass(".currentdiv").show();

Comment: but i will have to access the currently active div using its 'id'.
I want to know if there is a way to use a common function to do that..

Comment: acessing by id is jQuery("#yourID"). Or i misunderstand you?

Comment: yes...but i think i found a solution using classes...but with that too i'll have to make 30 diff code sections...thank you :)

Comment: If there is 30 equal code sections - then it's a logical error in your app. You may want to use data- attributes in your links to provide script information about div id you need to open-close when pressing this link.

Comment: For example: 
<a href="#" data-divid="div1" class="openerLink">
<div id="div1">Here is what you want</div>
<script>
jQuery.yourcallback = function () {
jQuery("#"+jQuery(this).attr("data-divid")).slideToggle();
}
jQuery(".openerlink").on("click",jQuery.yourcallback);
</script>

Comment: I didn't tried to launch that, but that is how you can make 1 function instead of 30 or more (if you want to add even more divs)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to all your div, then do something like this. This way you won't have to write 30 functions

```
function changeImg(id) {
    $('.your-divs').stop(true, true).fadeOut({ duration: slideDuration, queue: false });
    $('#change_content'+id).stop(true, true).fadeIn({ duration: slideDuration, queue: false });
}
```